# Modeling comments on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a Post model that looks like this:

```
#  id         :integer         
#  author_id  :integer         
#  owner_id   :integer         
#  owner_type :string(255)
#  content    :text    

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

The owner can be a User, Group, or a Place. I'm wondering what is the best approach to model a Comment. Considering that it shares most of its attributes with Post, I thought that the same Post model could serve as Comment using a relation like:

```
has_many :comments, class_name: 'Post', :as => :owner
```

But indeed I'm not happy at all with this solution since Post uses the same relation for storing its owner.

It's better to create a different model for comment? What about STI?

Comment: Why not create a polymorphic association for your comments model so you that you can access it from any model.

Comment: Do you mean to create a different model for comments? Or add another polymorphic relation to Post?

Comment: Yes I mean create a polymorphic association where if you need to access comments on any model you can. Check out this [railscast](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F154-polymorphic-association&ei=DBdYUvW4JMPMrQHc9oDwBQ&usg=AFQjCNHpILCNJ9HJvtVlIgicIwXODNVjoA&sig2=EnsraxO4E5201rKj0hAD_Q)  which explains what I'm trying to explain, alot better.

Comment: Well, I know how polymorphic relations works, as you can see I'm already using them on the Post model (and on some more models), my concern is that I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use the Post model to represent a comment and thus use the same polymorphic relation for denoting the Comment parent.

Comment: I would not recommend using the post model to represent a comments. Take into account if you wanted to pull a comment information based on users, etc it would become overkill if you have posts and comments as the same "model".

Comment: I see, it's a battle between simplicity and DRYness, and the former has won this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an abstraction of the real world and keep the things simple (clear, succinct), my suggestion is to use a Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments
end
```

If you are planning to add comments to another entity, for example, photos, use a Polymorphic Association:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  #...
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for. At the end it's all about simplicity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The rails tutorial does exactly this: guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. It makes a blog with a posts model and a comments controller attached to it.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

run this

```
$ rails generate controller Comments
```

And add this to the generated controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?view=asciicast

It's a bit old, but it is one of the free ones.  You do want to create a different model for your comments, and you want to create a polymorphic association.